# Notice about new answer

Tags: discussion, answers, notifications

I didn't find any helpful information about this, so I decided to ask:

If I've answered a question which is one month old, will the author of that question receive a notice about the fact that I posted a new answer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you will. The age of the question doesn't matter; you will always receive a notification when somebody posts an answer to your question.

I just posted a [test answer (10k+)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/338201/4751173) to an old Meta question of yours so you can confirm that it works. <s>I will delete it later.</s> It has been deleted now that you verified it works.